# MongoDB Update for array of object

Tags: mongodb

I am having following document in mongodb

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("521aff65e4b06121b688f076"),
  "uuid" : "160597270101684",
  sessionId" : "160597270101684.1",
  "stamps" :
           {
            "currentVisit" : "1377500985",
            "lastVisit" : "1377500985"
   },
   visits : [
            {
             "page":"google.com",
             "method": "GET"
             }
            ]
 }
```

**Requirement:**

If `uuid` and `sessionId` is not present i will insert the document as above otherwise i have to push only the object to `visits` array.

Any help will be greatful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB supports an `upsert` option on [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) that updates the matching document if it exists, and inserts a new document if it doesn't exist.  In MongoDB 2.4+ you can use the [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert) operator to further tweak this to set certain fields *only* if the upsert performs an insert.

```js
db.test.update({ 
    uuid: "160597270101684", 
    sessionId: "160597270101684.1" 
  }, { 
    $setOnInsert: {
      stamps: {
        currentVisit: "1377500985", 
        lastVisit: "1377500985"
      }
    },
    $push:{
      visits: {
        page: "google.com",
        method: "GET"
      }
    }
  }, { upsert:true })
```

So in the above example, the `$push` to `visits` will always occur but the `$setOnInsert` to `stamps` will only occur if the matching document doesn't already exist.

Comment: Even though its not explicitly mentioned, it seems that stamps would be updated every time as the it contains the data about current and last visit.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by following upsert query:

```
db.session.update({"uuid" : "160597270101684", sessionId : "160597270101684.1"},
{$set:"stamps" :{"currentVisit" : "1377500985","lastVisit" : "1377500985"}},
 $push :{visits:{"page":"yahoo.com","method": "POST"}}},
{upsert:true})
```

You can use $addToSet instead of $push if you want to avoid duplicates